# Communication between two OT-networks possible?

Tags: openthread

Does OpenThread provide any possibility to send a message (e.g. broadcast) to another OpenThread network resp. is it possible to establish a data transfer between two OT-networks, assuming that both networks use the same masterkey and the channel, but not the same PANID?

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Thread devices configured with different PAN IDs cannot communicate directly over the 802.15.4 radio even if they share the same master key and channel. Either the devices need to communicate via border router(s) or the devices need to participate in two Thread networks simultaneously.